How to get 22nd date of the previous month in SQL
I want to add a column on my query which will provide me the 22nd day of the previous month. I can query first day and last day of the month but not sure how to bring the 22nd day of the previous month.
For example: 22/09/2024
How can I achieve this?
I want the query to return 22nd day of the previous month.

You can get the previous month, parse out the month and year and just combine it into a date and hardcode the day of the month.

Could you give an example or provide reference on how to do it

Check DATEADD, YEAR, MONTH and maybe DATETIMEFROMPARTS

You should add your SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 22 , EOMONTH (GETDATE(),-2)) as an answer - not as an edit to the question

I have rolled back the edit you made to add an answer to the question; as @MartinSmith stated, use the answer feature for answers.

So, presumably, 2024-12-31 should also yield 2024-11-22?

Another way, that avoids this magic 0 -> 1900-01-01:
DECLARE @LastMonth date = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, getdate());

SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@LastMonth), MONTH(@LastMonth), 22);

In English: Find the day exactly a month ago, then use its year and month to form a date with the day part being furnished by a constant.
You also mentioned in a comment the way I would have done it (and in fact started writing before I read the comments):
DECLARE @Today date = getdate();

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 22, EOMONTH(@Today, -2));

In English: take the last day of two months ago, and add 22 days.
If you want to add your own answer with that method, I'm happy to remove it from mine. For now, leaving it for completeness.

Thank you, this solves the issue, I have marked it as solutiohn

We can use DATEADD() and DATEDIFF() functions as follows:
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 21)  -- 2024-09-22


Thank you, I have tried DECLARE @Today DATE = GETDATE() SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 22 , EOMONTH (@Today,-2)) which also works. I will mark your response as answer

@biswadas I like your solution much more, think that's more natural and readable. Could you please add this as another answer?
